# Remote name could not be resolved "facebook.botframework.com"

Tags: botframework, dialogflow-es, facebook-messenger-bot

I am building facebook bot using Microsoft bot framework and api.ai but am facing the following errors

> Remote name could not be resolved for following urls
>
> facebook.botframework.com
> api.api.ai

Could anyone suggest something

Comment: Please post the code you're using, so we can assist you.

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for your reply, please find the attached code

Comment: Hi @Udit the issue appears to be unrelated to the Bot Framework specifically.  Based on the image you shared, the problem seems to be in how api.ai is being used.  Please edit your question, and provide the code you are using to interact with api.ai

Comment: Hi @EricDahlvang, thanks for your reply, I accept it may be due to api.ai for the api.ai name not resolved but name "facebook .botframework.com" being not resolved comes in Code shared (not part of the image) 

This code has nothing to do with api.ai but is part of botframework and uses Ityping from bot framework alone. Hence for this , if we consider in isolation, can you please have a look

Thanks Eric

Comment: I'm sorry but i have no idea why this would randomly happen.

Answer (score 0):

@Eric Dahlvang, please find details below

Both errors are frequent but not always

For facebook.botframework.com

the line of code which gives the error is 4th line in below code, sending the typing reply

```
var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
Activity isTypingReply = activity.CreateReply();
isTypingReply.Type = ActivityTypes.Typing;
// error in line below 
await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(isTypingReply);
```

Comment: Please edit the question, and provide the code you are using to call api.ai (on stack overflow, the format is not to add new answers but to edit your existing question in order to provide more information).

Comment: Hi @EricDahlvang , I have removed the code that is calling api.ai sdk and kept only the code used to call the Bot framework part. Can you consider the above code only that is giving error as it has nothing to do with api.ai anymore

Comment: Hi Eric, the issue is intermittent, during development we witness it around 2-3 times a day but no specific times. Sometimes we do not even witness the same for a day